# how to handle multiple currency in apache solr?

Tags: solr

The currency field type is defined in schema.xml. This is the default configuration of this type:

fieldType name="currency" class="solr.CurrencyField" precisionStep="8"
           defaultCurrency="USD" currencyConfig="currency.xml"

where we can set default currency to USD or any other currency.

Comment: you already set up defaultCurrency to USD, you could change it to another if you want. What's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Data indexing**

> In order to index the data with the defined currencyField we should
>   specify the value and the currency prefixed with a comma character.

For example:

```
<field name="price">21.99,EUR</field> 
<field name="price">18.99,USD</field>
```

To query:

```
fq=price:[5.00 TO 29.99,EUR]
```

> As you can see, after setting the value (or range) we have to specify
>   the comma character and the currency we are interested